# Is there a way to push the output value of a UTXO to the stack in Bitcoin script?

Tags: script, utxo, covenants

When defining the spending conditions for a UTXO can one use the output value in a script by pushing it to the stack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You can't push the value of the output being spent in Bitcoin Script as of December 2023.

It's been explored in some of the covenants proposal however. For instance with the Taproot upgrade on the Liquid sidechain, a [new `OP_INSPECTINPUTVALUE` was introduced](https://github.com/ElementsProject/elements/blob/master/doc/tapscript_opcodes.md) which allows to push the value of (any of) the input(s) onto the stack.